# Собственные классы в codeigniter

Tags: классы, codeigniter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить собственные классы в `codeigniter`, чтобы в стандартном классе, можно было иметь доступ к классу стороннему?

Answer (score 1):

[Creating Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) в документации

Comment: Спасибо. Так и сделал. Жаль что abstract class не поддерживает